# Генерация данных в .json файл

Tags: c#, json, generate

У меня есть задача: сгенерировать данные в программе, которые записываются при старте программы в файл `.json`.
Метод который их генерирует:

```
static Person GeneratePeopleFileJson()
        {
            return new Person
            {
                PersonalId = 1, Name = "Имя 1", Year = 2002, BirthYear = new DateTime(2002, 05, 05), DeathYear = null,
                PersonalId = 2,Name = "Имя 2",Year = 1951, BirthYear = new DateTime(1951,08,05),DeathYear = new DateTime(2001,04,04),
            };
        }
```

При одной строке генерируется все как нужно, а вот многострочную генерацию не могу реализовать.
Это данные, которые я должен получить в самом файле .json:

```
[{"PersonalId":1,"Name":" Имя 1","Year":2002,"BirthYear":"2002 - 01 - 05","DeathYear":null},{"PersonalId":2,"Name":" Имя 2","Year":1951,"BirthYear":"1951 - 08 - 05","DeathYear":"2001 - 04 - 04"}]
```

Так выглядит метод записывющий данные в файл:

```
static void WriteTestFilesJson(string pathOfPeople, string pathOfTimeline)
        {
            string fileReaded = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GeneratePeopleFileJson(), Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
            File.WriteAllText(pathOfPeople, fileReaded);
        }
```

Класс:

```
public class Person
        {
            public int PersonalId;
            public string Name;
            public int Year;
            public DateTime BirthYear;
            public DateTime? DeathYear;
        }
```

Comment: С помощью чего вы генерируете свой JSON? Используете какую-то библиотеку?

Comment: @AlexKrass отредактировал вопрос, это то что вы спрашиваете?

Comment: Я так понимаю это Newtonsoft.Json, тогда все должно работать, единственное вы должны методу передать список. А у вас в методе GeneratePeopleFileJson сейчас только один человек, а не List и код из вопроса приведет к ошибке на этом этапе.

Comment: @AlexKrass через new List передавать данные получается?

Comment: Да, поместите всех ваших Person в List и передайте методу: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });` Если не получится, то напишите, приведу пример.

Comment: @AlexKrass если можно, все-таки хорошо было бы пример, не могу передать в лист

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример для нескольких человек

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonalId;
    public string Name;
    public int Year;
    public DateTime BirthYear;
    public DateTime? DeathYear;
}

class Program
{
    static List<Person> GeneratePeoplesFileJson()
    {
        return new List<Person>() {
            new Person() { PersonalId = 1, Name = "Имя 1", Year = 2002, BirthYear = new DateTime(2002, 05, 05), DeathYear = null },
            new Person() { PersonalId = 2, Name = "Имя 2", Year = 2003, BirthYear = new DateTime(2003, 05, 05), DeathYear = null },
            new Person() { PersonalId = 3, Name = "Имя 3", Year = 2004, BirthYear = new DateTime(2004, 05, 05), DeathYear = new DateTime(2201,04,04) }
        };
    }

    static void WriteTestFilesJson(string pathOfPeople, string pathOfTimeline)
    {
        string fileReaded2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GeneratePeoplesFileJson(), Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
        File.WriteAllText(pathOfPeople, fileReaded2);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        WriteTestFilesJson("путь до файла", "");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Всегда выбирайте массив, когда есть выбор.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, это определенно решает проблему, буду знать